# Embed Mono: cannot find mono-2.0.dll

Tags: c++, mono, embed, mono-embedding

I'm on windows 8.1 using VS2012.

I am trying to follow http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/ to embed the Mono CLR into a C project. After some issue, I have it compiling now.
I used the .def file in the article: http://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/msvc/mono.def
Note that this file says: LIBRARY mono-2.0.dll

When I run it, I get an error that the mono-2.0.dll can not be located.

I have mono-3.2.3 installed and I don't see a mono-2.0.dll anywhere.

1. What mono .dll implements the mono_xxx API (like mono_jit_init)?
2. Do I need to set env-vars to have the mono folder known to the OS?

I am kind of worried that the document states that mono-2.0 is for older versions and 'mono' should be used - but mono.dll also does not exist...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this answer: [Getting/compiling Mono-2.0.dll for embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23025734/1970882)

> The libraries that you are looking for may be found in the bin directory of the mono installation folder. Actually, after installing [mono 3.2.3](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.2.3/windows-installer/mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe) there are two libraries in the MONO_INSTALLATION_PATH\bin\ directory: libmonoboehm-2.0.dll and libmonosgen-2.0.dll (you must choose either [Boehm](http://www.mono-project.com/Generational_GC) or [SGen](http://mono-project.com/Working_With_SGen) GC implementation)

(Links for `Boehm` and `SGen` now redirect to the same web page)

I have never used embedded Mono in Windows (I always use Linux) but perhaps changing in your `.def` file to those library names your program will work.

For example, for Boehm you must download [mono.def](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/msvc/mono.def) and edit it like this:

```
; file generated by create-windef.pl
LIBRARY libmonoboehm-2.0.dll
EXPORTS
```

For SGen, just download [monosgen.def](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/msvc/monosgen.def) and edit it in this way:

```
; file generated by create-windef.pl
LIBRARY libmonosgen-2.0.dll
EXPORTS
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two? It still says it can't find the assembly (now libmonosgen-2.0.dll). Do I need to set an environment variable?

Comment: @obiwanjacobi About the first question: The difference is the GC implementation. SGen should be better than Boehm. About the second one: it depends on how have you compiled your program. For example: what paths have you used for `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` options? Or better: what command have you used to compile and link your program?

Comment: I have no idea what CFLAGS and LDFLAGS are. I just setup the project in VS2012. Looking at the command lines for the compiler and linker, no FLAGS (C or LD) are used. But I added the bin folder to the PATH environment variable and I no longer get that error (now a totally different one ;-).

Comment: @obiwanjacobi I thought you were using gcc not Visual Studio. I guess if you have for example libmonosgen-2.0.dll in the same path as your .exe file it should also work.

Comment: @Gooseman: can you edit [the page](https://github.com/mono/website/blob/gh-pages/docs/advanced/embedding/index.md) in the Mono docs to fix the outdated information? Might save the next one that stumbles over this some time :)

Comment: @AlexanderKöplinger I did not even think about it xD. I will do it this weekend (I want to verify if everything is working on Windows, for the obiwanjacobi question and comments there could be something else wrong)

Comment: This is indeed the answer. Important to note is that the Mono install is 32-bits. I also had some issues with that - mixing up 32- and 64-bit dll's. Next piece of information would be a working manual on how to get a x64 of libmonosgen-2.0.dll...

Comment: @obiwanjacobi AFAIK there is no 64-bit version of Mono for Windows (you could try to compile one by yourself but for sure there will be issues)

Comment: @Gooseman I know! That is why I called for a "working manual" because the mono docs are usually hopelessly out of date... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your property manager in visual studio, just do a post build events to copy your dll to your executable folder. iirc the dll is in the etc folder for embed mono.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).