# Obtaining the latest version of Mono for use as an embedded scripting engine

Tags: .net, mono

A (Windows) project I'm working on uses Mono to provide a scripting interface through the use of C# plugins. This project was first started (not by me) in 2012 and uses Mono version 2 to accomplish that task. Since 3 years have passed since then, I think it would be a good idea to update it to the latest version. Besides, I would like to compile it from source myself for two reasons:

1. The current compilation (I presume it depends on the options it was compiled with) has zero debugging aid; if an error such as an uncaught exception in a thread occurrs, the default behavior of the Mono DLL is to call `ExitProcess`, without any error reporting/logging.
2. It would be helpful to have the debug database available when investigating crashes.

To summarize, I would like to ask the following questions:

- **What is the latest version of Mono I should use in this situation?**
- **Where can I obtain its source code to compile it for Windows?**
- **Does that version support .NET 4.5 (2.0 only supports up to 4)?**

I have found [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/) article but it only offers you to download precompiled Windows binaries and generate a DLL based on that. I have also read this question & answer: [Getting/compiling Mono-2.0.dll for embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961704/getting-compiling-mono-2-0-dll-for-embedding) but compiling it in Cygwin won't give me debug information as far as I understand, also, the OP states they want 2.0 and I want the latest version (which also confuses me, the answer mentions downloading Mono 3.2.3 but still refers to 2.0 DLLs).

Answer (score 0):

Get the source for Mono at https://github.com/mono/mono.

Yes, you do need Cygwin to build it on Windows, but only as part of the infrastructure. You can actually *compile* with Visual Studio, so no worries about having debug symbols you like and all the rest:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/windows/